# ASP.net MVC5 Razor - set value Html.IdFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In ASP.net MVC5 View, I want to check if the user is logged in so that I can assign the User name to to a control, or just "Guest" if he is not logged in.

The problem is that I just can't set the value, as I always have an error - "Error  CS1061  'MvcHtmlString' does not contain a definition for 'val' and no extension method 'val' accepting a first argument of type 'MvcHtmlString' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Te Script is below.

How can I correctly access the control, either to set the value or to set it read-only?

Thanks in advance!

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            @{var usr = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                if (@User.Identity.Name != "")
                {
                    usr = User.Identity.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    usr = "Guest";
                }
            }

            @Html.IdFor(model => model.UserCri).val(usr);
            @Html.IdFor(model => model.UserCri).attr("readonly", "readonly");
    </script>
}
```

Comment: `@Html.IdFor` does not generate a form control (it just outputs a value that would be used to generate an `id` attribute based on the name of the property - in your case `UserCri`)

Comment: It not really clear what you want to do, but you do not need scripts for this - you could just do `@if (User.Identity.Name != "") { <div>@User.Identity.Name<div> } else { <div>Guest</div> }`

Comment: Hi Stephen,

Thanks for your help. Win's reponse below is exactly what I was looking for!

Thx!

Comment: Why in the world would you want to use javascript for that! (and the user name should not be in a form control anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to mix Html Helper with jQuery code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var usr = '@(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? User.Identity.Name : "Guest")';
        $('#@Html.IdFor(model => model.UserCri)').val(usr);
    });
</script>
```